# Nested group by in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, group-by, aggregate-functions

I have this query as you can see :

```
SELECT  
    [LineId]
    ,[TestPackageId]
    ,[MaterialDescriptionId]
    ,isnull(sum([RequestQuantity]),0) as TotalMRC
    ,isnull(sum([QuantityDeliver]),0) TotalMIV
    ,isnull(sum([QuantityDeliverToMember]),0) totalIMIV
    ,isnull(sum([QuantityDeliver]),0) - isnull(sum([QuantityDeliverToMember]),0) as Warehouse
FROM 
    [SPMS2].[dbo].[ViewMTO2] 
GROUP BY
    [LineId], [TestPackageId], [MaterialDescriptionId]
```

The result is :

```
lindid   tp     matDes  mrc miv imiv    warehouse
101973  7927    61075   2   2   0       2
101991  8666    70721   1   1   0       1
102052  8751    71008   48  16  0       16
99626   8053    61075   0   0   0       0
```

The problem is warehouse and the value of that is false .The warehouse value just should be calculated by `MaterialDescriptionId` The value of warehouse just should be calculated like this :`TotalMIV-totalIMIV` not for each row (  [LineId],[TestPackageId],[MaterialDescriptionId]) just for each `MaterialDescriptionId` the true result is

```
lindid   tp     matDes  mrc miv imiv    warehouse
101973  7927    61075   2   2   0       2
101991  8666    70721   1   1   0       1
102052  8751    71008   48  16  0       16
99626   8053    61075   0   0   0       2
```

As you can see for both items `61075` should be 2.because it is calculated based on `MaterialDescriptionId`.

How can I do that in my query?

here is my `viewmto2` result  (null values are zero)

[image]

Comment: Can you add sample data of `ViewMTO2` table before grouping by

Comment: @Prdp see update dear

Comment: when you say that `warehouse` is based on `matDesc`, it makes your resultset a bit confusing.  Since your resultset is based on all 3 fields, but you want warehouse based only on 1, you'll have to make sure that when users see 2 and 2 on separate rows, they understand that the "total" for that `matDesc` value is really 2 and not 4. Will this be clear for your users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use separate subqueries to calculate Warehouse :

```
SELECT  
    [LineId]
    ,[TestPackageId]
    ,[MaterialDescriptionId]
    ,isnull(sum([RequestQuantity]),0) as TotalMRC
    ,isnull(sum([QuantityDeliver]),0) TotalMIV
    ,isnull(sum([QuantityDeliverToMember]),0) totalIMIV
    ,(select isnull(sum(b.[QuantityDeliver]),0) from viewmto2 b where b.[MaterialDescriptionId] = a.[MaterialDescriptionId]) -
     (select isnull(sum(b.[QuantityDeliverToMember]),0) from viewmto2 b where b.[MaterialDescriptionId] = a.[MaterialDescriptionId]) as Warehouse
FROM 
    [SPMS2].[dbo].[ViewMTO2] a
GROUP BY
    [LineId], [TestPackageId], [MaterialDescriptionId]
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need a subquery calculating the grouped warehouse value by `MaterialDescriptionId`:

```
SELECT  
    a.[LineId]
    ,a.[TestPackageId]
    ,a.[MaterialDescriptionId]
    ,isnull(sum(a.[RequestQuantity]),0) as TotalMRC
    ,isnull(sum(a.[QuantityDeliver]),0) TotalMIV
    ,isnull(sum([a.QuantityDeliverToMember]),0) totalIMIV
    ,b.Warehouse
FROM 
    [SPMS2].[dbo].[ViewMTO2] as a
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT
    MaterialDescriptionId, isnull((QuantityDeliver) - sum(QuantityDeliverToMember),0) as Warehouse
    FROM [SPMS2].[dbo].[ViewMTO2]
    GROUP BY MaterialDescriptionId) as b
ON 
a.MaterialDescriptionId = b.MaterialDescriptionId   
GROUP BY
    a.[LineId], a.[TestPackageId], a.[MaterialDescriptionId], b.Warehouse
```